# How to map image inside ListView.separated in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, mapping

right now I have screen that contains static image, but what I want is mapping my image inside ListView.separated so it will show different image in my screen. Mostly, resource that I have read always using property of `children` to map image, but inside ListView.separated, there is no `children` property, is there a way to map my image? and this is my code

```
Container(
                child: new ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      );
                    },
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 3,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return myImage(index);
                    }))

Widget myImage(int index) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          image: DecorationImage(image: images[index].image,fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      );
  }

  List<Image> images = [
  Image.asset("assets/images/logo1.png"),
  Image.asset("assets/images/logo2.png"),
  Image.asset("assets/images/logo3.png"),
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView.seperated` works similar to `ListView.builder` because you get an index flutter does the mapping for you just provide the widget you want it mapped to like this.

```
List<Image> images = [
    Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
    Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
    Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
  ];
  Widget myImage(int index) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
        image: DecorationImage(image: images[index].image, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: new ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            );
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return myImage(index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So with your code , is it true that I just need to declare my List of image like this ```List images=["resource image 1","resource image 2",...]```

Comment: yes you would just declare your list as ```List<Image> image = [image.asset(path)]``` if its a local image just like any other list

Comment: I have tried with your code and declare my image like this:```List<Image> images = [
  Image.asset("path to my img1"),
  Image.asset("path to my img2"),
  ];``` but I get error that say ```type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Image>' of 'function result'```

Comment: sure, I have edited my question with my complete code

Comment: when I run your code on my emulator set up like it runs just fine idk why you are getting an error where do you have your extracted widget

Comment: I get my mistake, I get an error because I put my ```List``` in wrong position, I write it outside my stateful class, after I move inside the code run perfectly. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it :DD